# Plone installation can't connnect <ipaddress>:8080 Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, installation, plone

I just installed Plone using the Unified Installer.  I jumped onto my browser and entered :8080 and it says it can't connect.  Did the same for :8080/manage and there is nothing there either.  Last night it did this as well, which is what prompted the re-installation.

I'm not sure what's going on here I've seen the same problem posted elsewhere with no concrete solution.  I opened the firewall up on port 8080, although on my first installation of Plone this wasn't necessary.  Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat --inet --inet6 -ln | grep 8080`?

Comment: nothing...no response from netstat on that command.

Comment: Then your service is either not running at all or not listening on that port.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually *start* the Zope server.

Instructions on how to do that were given to you by the installer output at the end, or you can read the included `README.txt` for details.